# Cannot echo the values in an array in Php

Tags: php

Why can't I echo the values in an array directly?

```
$list = array('Max', 'Alice', 'Brigitte');
echo($list); //This doesn't work 

//But this does    
foreach($list as $l){
        echo($l . " ");
    };
```

Comment: The exact answer in the main reference question can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/24507107#24507107

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because
echo — Output one or more STRINGS

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Try using var_dump for array
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

or print_r
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: You can also make it a string by gluing all elements together, `echo implode(", ", $list);`. Or access the values directly using the associated index, like `$list[1]` outputs "Alice" (because PHP starts on 0).

Answer (score 0):

You may have noticed that `echo($list);` *does* produce some output:

> Array

This is because `$list` is cast to a string in the context of `echo`. In fact, if you had warnings turned on, you would see a

> Notice: Array to string conversion

for that statement. The [defined behavior of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) when converting arrays to strings is that arrays are always converted to the string `"Array"`.

If you want to print the contents of the array without looping over it, you will need to use one of the various PHP functions that converts an array to a string more effectively. For a simple array of strings like your `$list`, you can just use `implode`.

```
echo implode(', ', $list);
```

But if you need to deal with a more complex array (if some elements are themselves arrays, for example) this will not work because of the same array to string conversion issue.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see if I can explain this in a good way. Basically $list has a lot of more elements and things associated with it. When echoing $list it doesn't really know how to handle it. It has to do with how array data types work in PHP.