# Does echo cast non-string variables into string type on the fly?

Tags: php, variables, types, echo

I've just came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213661/3429430) mentioning that `echo` can only print string(s), that's why we cannot print the full array. But, we can easily echo integers and floats etc like this:

```
$int = 3;  $float = 3.456;  
echo $int, "</br>", $float;
```

I was just wondering does `echo` cast these variables to `string` type behind the scenes?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if there is a fuller answer (a duplicate) but `echo` will try and convert any parameter to a string - objects will have the `__toString()` method called (if there is one).

Comment: @NigelRen Would you be able to provide any reference like something from the php manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the section on [Converting to string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) from the manual:

> String conversion is automatically done in the scope of an expression
>   where a string is needed. This happens when using the echo or print
>   functions, or when a variable is compared to a string.